# MatTableDataSource not containing the data Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to use the `MatTableDataSource` to make sure that I can use all functions of the `MAterial Data-Table.` Unfortunately, it does not seem to work.

I retrieve the data from an API, put this into an object (which gets filled) and then create a new `MatTableDataSource`, but it does not display any data on the page. If I change the `datasource` in the html file to the actual list I put into the `MatTableDataSource` it does show data.

**.ts file code**

```
 weekView : PlanningCalendarWeek = new PlanningCalendarWeek();

 displayedColumnsWeek = this.buildDisplayedColumsWeek();

 weekViewDataSource;

 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getTimePhasing();
   this.headerweekList = new Array<string>();
   this.createHeadersForWeek();
   this.weekViewDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.weekView.machineTypePlannings);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `weekView.machineTypePlannings`?

Comment: You must try assigning weekViewDataSource inside the subscribe method of the function in which you getting the value of weekView.

Comment: @bugs I get this weekView.machineTypePlannings in the function this.getTimePhasing(); It does an API call.

Comment: @Prachi I can not do this because of the model weekView contains two lists. Where as only one of those should be in the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem! Thank you @Prachi. My data list was still undefined when assigning it to the datasource the following line fixed it:

```
this.dataService.getTimePhasedWeekView().subscribe(planning => {
  this.weekView = planning;
  this.weekViewDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(planning.machineTypePlannings);
});
```